# Python 'with open' print text file

Tags: python

I am trying to add a print to text file for my results as well as the cmd line list that displays. And tried using `with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:`. Though the code already uses `with open(lic) as f:`.  Can I use multiple "with open" statements?  How can I generate a file text printout in addition to the cmd line list?

```
import time

fips_dict = {}
fips_dict["02000"]="AK"
fips_dict["02013"]="AK, Aleutians East"
fips_dict["02016"]="AK, Aleutians West"

while 1: #repeat forever
count = 0
lic = "//Server/replicated/Userdata/"+raw_input("Account: ")+"/Dmp/LicenseStyle.xml"
print
try: #error handling
    with open(lic) as f:
        for line in f:
            #get and print fips codes and county names
            if 'RampEntry' in line:
                count += 1
                fips_index = line.index('dataValue')+11
                code = line[fips_index : fips_index+5]
                statecode = line[fips_index : fips_index+2]
                if code.isalnum():
                    print code,fips_dict[code]
                elif statecode.isalpha():
                    print "Entire State of", statecode
                    print
                else:
                    print "format error in", lic
except IOError: #if file not found
    print lic[23:],"not found"
except KeyError: #if no match for FIPS
    print "not found"
except:
    print "an unexpected error has occured!"
print
now = time.strftime("%c")
print ("%s"  % now )
print
```

Comment: You can have multiple `with open`s at the same time, just give each of the file handles a different name; don't call them all `f`.

Comment: You can even declare them both at the same time if that makes sense (e.g. `with open(lic) as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:`).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the quick tips! I'll give them a try.

Comment: I've updated the "with open" statement in the above code with "with open(lic) as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:", and now the output.txt file generates though it doesn't include the list the cmd line displays. It is blank.

Comment: What do I need to add to inject the list into the text file?